# contar valores distintos e agrupar ao mesmo tempo

Tags: sql, count, distinct, sum, sqlfiddle

Tenho uma tabela com varias cidades e bairros, preciso retornar quantos bairros são citados por cidade.

usaria count e distinc ?

[image: Tabela esperada]

Comment: Como está sua tabela que guarda essas informações?

Comment: CREATE TABLE tb_listings (
  "advertiser_id" varchar,
  "listing_id" varchar,
  "portal" varchar,
  "city" varchar,
  "neighborhood" varchar);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é utilizar `count`, `distinct` e `group by`

Essa consulta apresenta a quantidade de bairros por cidade e bairro.

```
SELECT   city, 
         neighborhood, 
         count(neighborhood) as qtd_bairros 
FROM     <nomenclatura da tabela> 
GROUP BY city, 
         neighborhood 
ORDER BY city, neighborhood DESC
```

Essa consulta apresenta a quantidade de bairros por cidade:

```
SELECT city, 
       count(DISTINCT neighborhood) qtd_bairros 
FROM   <nomenclatura da tabela> 
GROUP  BY city 
ORDER  BY city DESC
```

Comment: Então essa conta retorna o numero de linhas por cidade, eu precisava dele por bairro e cidade na mesma tabela ? consigo fazer isso?

Comment: Boa , já me ajudou a clarear a ideia uma duvida no "count " eu consigo contar mais de uma coluna ? ali contou bairro precisava contar nbairro e cidade, por exemplo quantas vezes apareceu santo andre

Comment: @Carvalho, a quantidade de cidade por cidade e bairro?

Comment: isso imagine 3 colunas, 1 com numeors de vezes que aquela cidade apareceu, a 2 com numero de bairros quantas vezes apareceu e o 3 com o percentual entre eles. Preciso responder qual percentual daquele bairro perante a cidade

Comment: @Carvalho, se não for problema apresentar a quantidade mais de uma vez para cada registro, uma possibilidade é colocar o resultado de uma subquery para uma coluna. SELECT   city, 
         neighborhood, 
         count(neighborhood) as qtd_neighborhood,
         (select count(city) FROM <nomenclatura da tabela> WHERE city = tbl.city) as qtd_city
FROM     <nomenclatura da tabela>  tbl
GROUP BY city, 
         neighborhood
ORDER BY city, neighborhood DESC;

Comment: Era isso mesmo muito obrigado, na ultima coluna que eu comparo percentual de imoveis por bairro posso usar essa formula : ( 100. * count(*) / sum(count(*)) over () as decimal(10,2))  exite algo mais clean ?